# Difference between afFieldInput and afQuickField?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am working on autoform package in meteor. I would like to know the differences between `afFieldInput` and `afQuickField` and on what basis do we need to choose `afFieldInput` or `afQuickField`, examples would help more to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically an `afQuickField` will render titles, form groups, etc, whereas the `afFieldInput` will only render the relevant HTML `input` tag. `afQuickField` can also handle `Object` and `Array` types, which `afFieldInput` can't.

Comment: Thanks Thomas ,I asked this question because in afQuickField we have option "required" ,do we have any options in afFieldInput

Comment: `required` is something you would normally specify in the schema. So the `afFieldInput` will pick it up from there. (Note that is is basically the opposite of `optional`.) Options that work directly are listed [here](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#affieldinput)